# Removing Rails, jRuby and RubyGems completely

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I had Ruby, jRuby, RubyGems and Rails installed in Ubuntu 14.04. I needed to upgrade or downgrade some packages to exact versions. I tried to uninstall each of the above packages completely.

First I removed all packages installed using `gem install`:

```
gem uninstall package
```

Then I used `sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby1.9.1-dev ruby1.9.1-full rubygems jruby`

But, still some binary files and folders are left:

```
/usr/local/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rake

/var/lib/gems/
/usr/lib/jruby/
/var/lib/jruby/
```

I want to get rid of all the above files and folders to avoid any future conflict. `sudo apt-get remove` showing that they are not installed. Shall I remove them manually one by one or is there some other way? I am afraid that any manual removal might mess up my system.

Comment: If you're intended to upgrade then consider using rvm or rbnev next time for managing ruby with ease. I think you can remove them manually or leave them as it is, it won't affect anything.

Comment: As @Surya said, use [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [RBEnv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to manage your Rubies. By default they put them in your home directory, and allow you to have multiple versions, switching versions as you deem necessary. Both are very robust; RVM is more feature-complete but that comes at the cost of being more complex. RBEnv is simpler, and not as intrusive. I use them both. Closely follow RVM's installation directions if you decide to go with it. We see a LOT of misconfigured RVM questions here because people didn't do that.